# String patterns in BASH

Tags: bash

I'm trying to check if a string is in the following format: (X,Y,Z) where  -99<=X,Y,Z<=99.

From some strange reason the following doesn't do the job:

```
if [[ "${line}" == "("[-99-99],[-99-99],[-99-99]")" ]];
    then echo "nice point"
fi
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This is called `regex abuse`. Values in brackets `[` and `]` mean `character class` and roughly: it will match _any **one** character from the specified set_ i.e. it will search _minus_, or any digit character from _nine_ to _nine_ (to search for more characters you will need `quantifier` right after the class). Also operator `==` doesn't feel the `regexp`, you will need `=~` instead to put it into play.

Comment: Not a very strange reason, but quite reasonable reason. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
if [[ $line =~ ^\(-?[0-9]{1,2},-?[0-9]{1,2},-?[0-9]{1,2}\)$ ]]; then
    echo "nice point"
fi
```

Comment: Can you please refer me to some test which will make me understand why this works.
Thanks!

Comment: @Doppelganger ``=~`` is a syntax for extended regular expressions in bash. The way it works is quite simple: ``^`` - start of the line, ``\(`` - escaped symbol, ``-?`` minus sign zero or one time, ``[0-9]{1,2}`` digit repeated one or two times and so on... ``$`` means the end of the line. All that stuff is explained perfectly on [wikipedia page about regexps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Answer (score 1):

Your code compares the content of `${line}` with the glob pattern `"("[-9],[-9],[-9]")"`. Glob patterns aren't very powerful and they especially can't compare number ranges.

My solution would be:

```
echo "${line}" | awk -F, '{ 
    ok=0;
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        v=$1;
        if(-99 <= v && v <= 99) {ok++;}
    }
    if( ok != 3) { exit 1 }
} '
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "nice point"
fi
```

`-F,` tells `awk` to split the input at commas. The loop then iterates over all fields in the line (= each value). It increments `ok` for each value that is between -99 and 99.

If `ok` is not 3 after the loop, then `awk` exits with a non-zero exit code. This is then checked in the if.

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression should work in `bash`. It checks for 2-digit numbers preceded by an optional negative sign. The numbers can be separated by optional spaces.

```
twodigitnum="-?[[:digit:]]{1,2}"
regex="^\($twodigitnum, *$twodigitnum, *$twodigitnum\)$"
if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "nice point"
fi
```

Comment: This is not going to work. Returns ``nice point`` for that string ``(-5,25,-99)asdads``

Comment: Added start and end anchors to fix that problem.

Comment: Also note that simple regex solutions are going to accept strings like ``'(-05,09,-00)'``

Answer (score 0):

[ and ] match a set of characters, not a numeric range.  So [-99-99] doesn't do what you think - it only matches the two characters "-" and "9".

In bash you can use extended globbing to match this, like so:

```
[[ "${line}" == "("?(-)+([0-9]),?(-)+([0-9]),?(-)+([0-9])")" ]]
```

... that allows any number of digits, you could fine tune that if necessary.